# How do you apply an even CSS stroke to an SVG path?

Tags: css, svg, stroke

I have an SVG:

```css
path{
fill: transparent;
stroke: #35a4e8;
stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 118 118" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m0 117.999999.087436-99.4506004 49.406364-18.13336901 68.5062-.41602959v117.999999z" />
</svg>
```

But the stroke is uneven. The top left corner looks a lot thicker than the other sides.

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a way I can get an even 4px stroke on all sides?

Comment: Use a larger viewBox. In your example half of the stroke falls outside the svg canvas. Please try `viewBox="-2 -2 122 122"`

Comment: @enxaneta Yes, that worked. What is the relationship between the X and Y `viewBox` values and the stroke? Seeing as the stroke is `4px` and the X and Y are `-2`, I figured it might be half the stroke as a negative value, but using a stroke of `8px` and `-4` as the X and Y did not work the same.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. It seems the X and Y of the `viewBox` need to be half of the stroke and then you need to add the stroke value to both the `width` and the `height` of the `viewBox` (i.e. if the original viewBox is `0 0 180 180`, then with a stroke of `8px` the new viewBox needs to be `-4 -4 188 188`).

Comment: You can also try `svg{overflow:visible}` If the svg element has a border or an outline you can see clearly half of the stroke falling outside.